# How do i move the flashing cursor along the text as if its a normal cursor with the 2 buttons? If possible vanilla javascript is preferable

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to have it move back and forth with the button presses as if its an actual cursor

```
<div>
hello<span id="hi"></span>
</div>

<button onclick="move('left')">left</button>
<button onclick="move('right')">right</button>
```

i can't figure out how to locate the span in the text and then move it to the side with the button presses so it goes from hello| to hell|o with one press to the left

```
function move(direction){
      switch (direction) {

        case "left":
            break;

        case "right":
            break;
    }
}
```

all the css is fine

```
 span {
  content: '';
  width: 3px;
  height: 17px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: blink 0.5s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you need to think about this is that your document is a tree (as in the data structure) because that is how the browser sees it. That means means the part that you are working with is three sections:

```
div
.....[text]
..... span
.....[text]
div
```

All three are children of your parent div, so they will be in its `childNodes` collection. Two are [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text), the other is a [span element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSpanElement).

The `text` node type has a `textContent` property, which you can use to get or set the text within the node. Something like this:

```
const myDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]; // assuming you only have one div, more practical to give your div an id and use document.getElementById("my-id");
myDiv.childNodes[0].textContent = "hello";
```

This looks a little homework-adjacent and certainly seems a good opportunity for learning, so instead of writing the code, I'll take the long cut. The process I would go through in your function is:

1. Find the parent `div` - perhaps having an `id` on it would make that easier.
2. Read the `textContent` of its first child.
3. Read the `textContent` of its last child.
4. If you're moving left you want to remove the last character from the first child and put it on the start of the last child. If the first child is empty, do nothing.
5. If you're moving right you want to remove the first character of the last child and put it on the last character of the first child. If the last child is empty, do nothing.

Note that doing it this way, we aren't doing anything with the `span` we are moving the text around it instead.

For extra flourish you could create an object that maintains references to the text nodes in question so you don't have to retrieve them each time a button is clicked.

Comment: uhhh problem i have tried textContent, innerHTML, and innerText and i can't seem to get the text of the children

Comment: What does your `move` function look like now?

Comment: function move(direction){
switch (direction) {
  case "left":
firstend = text1.charAt(text1.length-1);
    alert(firstend);
    break;

    case "right":
secondend = text2.charAt(0);
    alert(secondend);
      break;
}}

but i dont know how to determin the character that i removed

Comment: Internally you might take the two text nodes when you create your object, combine their value into a single char array and have an int index for the span location. `let chars = (leftNode.textContent + rightNode.textContent).split(); let cursorLocation = leftNode.textContent.length;` then have a `generateText` function that basically goes `for ( let i = 0; i< this.chars.length; i++) { if ( i<this.cursorLocation) { leftNode.textContent += this.chars[I] } else { rightNode.textContent += this.chars[I]; }` and so on. Then move changes `cursorLocation` and calls `generateText`.

Comment: sorry but im pretty new to javascript so to my understanding let chars is combining then splitting the nodes. and let cursorLocation makes no sense but there is a loop at the start.

Comment: `cursorLocation` here is where your span is sitting - we have split "hello" and "" into [ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'] and we know the cursor location is 5 because it is after the end of "hello". When we change `cursorLocation` to 4 we then we take steps 0 -4 ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l' ] and put those in the left text node, then put the [ 'o'] into the right node. You could do that with `this.chars.slice(0, 4).join()` and `this.chars.slice(4, 1).join()` if you didn't want the `for` loop there.

Comment: my code so far is 

` let leftNode = document.getElementById("first");`
    `let rightNode = document.getElementById("second");`
`let chars = (leftNode.textContent + rightNode.textContent).split(); `
`let cursorLocation = leftNode.textContent.length;`

    
  `function move(direction){`
`switch (direction) {`
 `case "left":`
   `this.chars.slice(0, 4).join(); `
 `this.chars.slice(4, 1).join();`
`break;`

  `case "right":`

    `break;`
`}}`

and i keep getting type errors saying that it cant read text content

Comment: ok i fixed the first type error now i have 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
    at move (/script.js:10:16)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (/:13:32)

Comment: i did it! i used charAT and substring to move it around

Comment: Good job, I knew you'd get there.